# How to scale down an image and lower resolution in Pshop CS3?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I scale down a large high res photoshop image to thumbprint size @ lower the resolution? I have Photoshop CS3.
thank you, carolpix

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Image > Image Size` and then make any required adjustments to the size and resolution in the window that pops up.